# Xpath for href elements

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

Can some one help me in finding the `Xpath` expression for

```
<div class="row 2">         
 <a href="URL1" class="class 1">display this </a>
</div>
```

the same `URL1` is used many times in the code

Comment: what is this ? No xml no input, not clear at all. Please provide precise explanation of problem with all required inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find your element with a CSS selector :

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(
    "div[class='row 2'] > a[class='class 1'][href$='URL1']"));
```

To find your element with an XPath :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(
    "//div[@class='row 2']/a[@class='class 1'][text()='display this ']"));
```

Comment: This helped me finding Xpath for other elements too. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Try this `Xpath`:

```
//a[@href="URL1"][text()="display this "]
```

Comment: URL1 is used many times and when i am using the above one you provided it is selecting all the places which has URL1

Answer (score 1):

I'm suggesting you try using `By.linkText()` as :

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("display this"));
```

or using `By.partiaLinkText()` as :

```
driver.findElement(By.partiaLinkText("display this"));
```

or using `By.cssSelector()` as :

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.row a.class"));
```

If none of the above locate your desire element correctly then try using `By.xpath()` as :

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".//a[contains(text(), 'display this')]"));
```

Comment: It seems that there is an extra space present in link text, so your expression will not match target element.. or maybe it's just a flaw in provided `HTML` :)

Comment: @Andersson may be, that's why I suggested some different locator as well..:)

Comment: All of those helped thanks guys

Comment: @swathi9 yes, linkText works with  only `a` element with contains text, if there is not text, try other locator then..:)

Answer (score 1):

XPath is the path down html elements that leads directly to the element you are looking for. In your example there are no html or body tags, so I cant tell you the exact path, but if you download [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), you can use that tool (in Firefox) to find the exact element you want, then right click the html for the element and copy the exact XPath.

[image]